# Как сделать запрос с Авторизацией (Python, urllib.request)

Tags: python, авторизация, get, камера, urllib

Как сделать запрос с Авторизацией ?

Раньше можно было на ip-камеру без авторизации заходить ( после обновления это закрыли :((( )

```
img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
img_temp.write(urllib.request.urlopen(camera.url).read())
img_temp.flush()
```

где camera.url = http://IP/snapshot.cgi
так не работает http://IP/snapshot.cgi?user=[USERNAME]&pwd=[PASSWORD]

камера aircam Ubiquiti

Чё почитать , куда рыть ?

Comment: А как происходит авторизация на сайте, вы выяснили? И почему не пользуетесь [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python urllib2, basic HTTP authentication, and tr.im](http://stackoverflow.com/q/635113/4279)